# Trying to update field when an opportunity is changed to closed/won stage and has a lineitem that is no longer active for that pricebook

Tags: pricebook, product

Why is my trigger below not updating the field that i am wanting to use in my validation?

```
trigger OpportunityValidationonClosed_Won on Opportunity (after update) {

Set<id>prod2id = new Set<id>();
prod2id = Trigger.newMap.keySet();
Map<Id, Integer>productcnt = new Map<Id, Integer>();
List<OpportunityLineItem>opplist=[Select Product2Id, Opportunity.stagename, Opportunity.testopp__c, OpportunityId, Opportunity.pricebook2Id From OpportunityLineItem];
//List<Opportunity>opplist=[SELECT id, TestOpp__c, Pricebook2Id FROM Opportunity WHERE StageName = 'Closed/Won' and id IN (SELECT OpportunityId FROM OpportunityLineItem)];

AggregateResult[] inactiveprod = [SELECT Product2Id, count(Pricebook2Id) FROM PriceBookEntry WHERE IsActive = false GROUP BY Product2Id];

For (AggregateResult ar : inactiveprod) 
{
    productcnt.put((Id) ar.get('Product2Id'), (integer) ar.get('expr0'));

}

For(OpportunityLineItem opp : opplist)
{

    if(opp.opportunity.stagename == 'Closed/Won' && productcnt.get(opp.product2Id) > 0)
    {


        opp.opportunity.TestOpp__c = true;
        //opp.stagename.addMessage('There is an inactive product and cannot be in Closed/Won stage until product is removed');

        //continue;



    }
       update opp;   
  }

}
```